# Trying to remove vowels from user input with function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to remove vowels via user input. I have tried all sorts of things and looked up other question here as well and its just not working.

```
def d_vowel(word):
    word = input('give me a word: ')
    vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']
    new_word = []
    for letter in word[:]:
        if not letter.lower() in vowels:
            new_word.append(letter)

    print(''.join(new_word))

d_vowel()
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. It seems like you have forgotten to ask a question in your question. Please read the sections [ask] and [MCVE].

Comment: What's the problem? This is very vague.

Comment: What's wrong? It's working perfectly after removing the `argument from function.`

Comment: @Carcigenicate what do you mean its working perfectly? I get the prompt, I enter a word (per the prompt) and it prints the word unchanged. If I type 'hello', I get 'hello'. But I want 'hll'.

Comment: Here's your code after removing the argument `word` from the `d_vowel()` function-

The Code:

 `def d_vowel():
  word = input('give me a word: ')
  vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']
  new_word = []
  for letter in word[:]:
   if not letter.lower() in vowels:
    new_word.append(letter)

  print(''.join(new_word))

 d_vowel()`

**Input**

    `give me a word: Hello world`

**Output**

 `   Hll wrld`

Comment: @JoshBennett You tagged the wrong person, but I checked it as well, and it works fine. "hello" yields "hll" as expected. The only change I made was to get rid of the call to `input` since it isn't needed, but that shouldn't effect anything.

Comment: I am running it in terminal and I keep getting the same result. WTF!

Comment: @JoshBennett That would only be possible if the letters being entered were weird variations of normal letters,  or old versions of the code were being run. Restart your environment, because you can tell just looking over the code that it's not a problem with the code itself.

Comment: The only weird things with your code here at the fact that you have `word` as a paremeter, but then just overwrite it with the return from `input`, and the fact that you're copying `word` using `[:]` before iterating, which isn't necessary. Neither of those things will cause the behavior you're mentioning though.

Comment: I figured it out. Also removed the [:]. good point.

Comment: the input statement was just for giggles